# RockShox Recon Gold fork problem

Tags: fork, suspension, sram

I have a RockShox Recon Gold (100mm travel) fork, 2017 year of production.
I have made 150 hours service. Followed the instructions carefully, disassembled it, have cleaned everything, changed seals and foam rings, put the right amount of correct RockShox original oils into lower legs, damper, and air chamber.
Assembled it carefulle.
Then I pumped the correct pressure (85psi) into the piston.

After all that my fork stopped working correctly at all.
It now travels for only about 15mm, and then it hits some solid resistance as if a wall. Rebound is slow and makes weird noises.

What should I do about it?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There’s only really two possibilities: either something is broken or you didn’t assemble the fork correctly.

You can disassemble the fork and recheck all your work, or you can go to a local bike repair shop.

From your description of the fork behavior I’d guess that there is too much oil somewhere or oil in the wrong place.

Comment: Thank you! Well I have started dissassembling, and first bad thing was, when I knocked over the half udone bolts to remove the lower legs, from the damper leg a lot of oil has started to drain. Too many. It was obviously the 133ml of oils that I put into the damper upper leg side.

Comment: So I removed lower legs and notices, then the air side was functioning ok, but the damper side has a leaking problem. So it probably is something wrong with the seals in damper upper legs. Because lot of oil, may be all of it, drained from upper leg to lower lef obviously. Will be looking itno it more.

Comment: @momijigari That would definitely be your problem. Sounds like you didn't reinstall the damper seals properly, or the new seals and/or damper stanchion are damaged. What you've done is hydrolocked your fork - the bottom half is full of incompressible oil, so there's no room for the top half to compress down into it. Don't ride it as it is currently.